# Running old Metaio SDK iOS offline for demo purpose? MetaioLicenseString

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, metaio

I developed a Metaio Demo app last year, now i want to run the application again for some demo purposes.
Since Metaio was sold to apple last year, the SDK tells me that my license key has expired.
I learned from stack overflow, that the MetaioLicenseString is validated offline by the SDK.
Is there a way to make the SDK validate my old demo MetaioLicenseString by e.g setting back my system time?

So far, i did not have any luck with that approach. From the metaio dev portal i remember that i had to provide the app name,
the application ID, and the SDK Version. (See Screenshot [1]) So my assumption is, that the MetaioLicenseString is generated from these information + an expiration date.

Any clue how i could approach this in order to get my old app running (just offline for single demo purpose)

[1] https://my.metaio.com/helpdesk/upfiles/createkeyforappios_1.png

Comment: You would save time just to switch to another SDK. If Metaio was developed correctly (which I would assume), it should expose two events, OnTrackFound and OnTrackLost (or similar). Those can be found in any AR SDK. You would just have to rewrite a bit your listener script.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a metaio account, contact metaio support at contact(at)metaio.com. (Yes, there is still someone, but just 
till the end of april or beginning of june.)
Past year, before closing the dev portal, Metaio had released a license signature generator which could be downloaded from their portal , if you had a dev account. 
So try writing them and kindly ask if they would help you.

But, I have to say that you will probably get warnings from the Google Play store , if you publish a metaio SDK app. Concerning SSL issues.

Good luck.